# bashrc Alias for PWD basename in nested quote does not update depending on current directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to use the name of the current directory in an alias in my `.bashrc` file. I'm using `basename $PWD` to get the current directory name and adding it using a nested quote in bash. My `.bashrc` has this command:

```bash
alias test="echo $(basename $PWD)"
```

The issue is that when I call this command in my terminal it doesn't use my *current* PWD but always uses the home PWD `~/`. I.e.:

```bash
~/$ test
USERNAME
~/$ cd Documents
~/Documents$ test
USERNAME # <<< Should be Documents
```

Anyone know why the PWD doesn't update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used double quotes, `$(basename $PWD)` is evaluated immediately and the *result* is used to define the alias. Use single quotes, or better yet, define a function instead of an alias.

```
my_func () {
    echo "$(basename $PWD)"
}
```

Don't name the alias `test`, because that shadows the standard `test` command (though it is more commonly referred to by its alias `[`).

Comment: Thank you! Solution was to change whole alias expression from double quotes `"` to single quotes `'`. This was sufficient to not "store" the PWD value upon sourcing of the `.bashrc` file. +1

Comment: Get used to using functions for dynamically changing states. Aliases cause more problems than they are worth. Glad you solved your immediate problem. Good luck.

Comment: That's still a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)